# Opencart Category path remove in product page

Tags: php, mysql, shopping-cart, opencart

In Opencart - I want the below url has to change 
http://ecbiz111.inmotionhosting.com/~dvdcdd5/store/index.php?route=product/product&path=20_59&product_id=110

into

http://ecbiz111.inmotionhosting.com/~dvdcdd5/store/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=110

Need to remove "path=" query string and show only the product id in the query string even i have clicked from the category path.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: what problem 'path' is giving to you??

Answer (score 0):

If you want this for a better seo why don't you use SEF links by opening seo from admin panel.

Else you need to define a way to assign categories to products. And then change URL creation function as you wish (according to the assigned category-to-product definition) But you may need to change many files for this. Because $route  $url etc. and breadcrumb like logics will require that information.

Comment: thank for your reply, if i enable SEO links it is not working properly. I want the SEO link link below http://<SiteName>/CategoryName/ProductName/ProductId. Please help me out what i have to do in htaccess level as well as admin level. Main thing it wont affect the google indexing with same product associated with different category.

Comment: seo links are very useful but there is no usage as you explain in opencart. you wish a url structure like wordpress it seems. But believe me sitename/WHATEVERYOULIKE is a better solution for seo especially by adding ProductID you are killing your seo beauty. You dont also need to show category (they are also in breadcrumb and tags if you set tags) but if you insist just add categoryname before all seo-urls from admin panel seperate with - instead of / . That will be static but believe it retuns great results.

Answer (score 0):

You should open catalog/controller/product/category.php and find this code (line 171)

```
'href' => $this->model_tool_seo_url->rewrite(HTTP_SERVER .
'index.php?route=product/product&path=' . $this->request->get['path'] .
'&product_id=' . $result['product_id'])
```

remove

```
&path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '
```